# Logstash "UNIX" date format to Human Readable

Tags: date, logstash, nagios

I am using logstash to parse nagios logs. Currently I have the following in my filter.

```
date{
        locale => en
        match =>["nagios_epoch", "UNIX"]
        target => "nagios_time"
}
```

My output is, "2015-07-21T23:16:36.000Z". How can I convert this to a human readable date/time format? Something like, Jul 21 15:05:17. I've tried using grok to separate into day, month, time, etc. but I keep running across errors. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Grok is a good way; what error do you get?

Comment: I can successfully use grok, and get the fields, but I'm unsure how to pass them through the date filter afterwards.

Comment: I thought you were trying to make a string from the fields.  You wouldn't use date{} for that.  Did I misunderstand?

Comment: From my understanding there are ways to achieve that format. I implemented grok{} but I think I may be doing something wrong. I am wondering if there is an easy way achieve a result that look something like this, Jul 21 15:05:17.

Comment: date{} creates date objects, which are UTC (epoch).  If you want a string, you need to make the fields and combine them yourself.